# Organize a large Project with multi private cocoapods

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

so after looking at [this article](http://dev.hubspot.com/blog/architecting-a-large-ios-app-with-cocoapods), it seems using private cocoapods to modularize a large app is workable. but I ran into a problem: how to use / create private cocoapods between multi developers?

currently, I use the simplest solution: use git source as pod directly, like this:

```
pod 'HBToolkit', :git => 'ssh://private-domain.com/ios/hbtoolkit.git'
pod 'HBBussiness', :git => 'ssh://private-domain.com/ios/hbbussiness.git'
pod 'HBAPI', :git => 'ssh://private-domain.com/ios/hbpapi.git'
```

it's really very convenient, but the bad thing is it can't deal dependency. so suppose moduleA depend on moduleB and moduleC, there is no way to identifier them in `XXX.podspec`, since private pod with directly git source is not supported in cocoapods.

in order to resolve the dependency, I have to follow the [steps provided by the site](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html), which is a bit complicated.

so how to achieve the effect like the article provided:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

# networking, slider navigation, routing
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.2.1'
pod 'ViewDeck', '~> 2.2.11'
pod 'JLRoutes', '~> 1.2'

# sub-apps, pulling from the head of each repo for development. alternately, we can pin it to a release version like we do the other pods
pod 'HSAPIClient', :head
pod 'HSCommonResources', :head
pod 'HSMarketingGraderApp', :head
pod 'HSContactsApp', :head
pod 'HSDashboardApp', :head
pod 'HSLoginApp', :head
pod 'HSSocialApp', :head
pod 'HSSourcesApp', :head
pod 'HSSettingsApp', :head
pod 'HSSocialReach', :head
pod 'HSEmailApp', :head
```

PS: in multi developers senior, if I want to see the result in the final app, do I have to do the process:

1. edit source in moduleN
2. commit and push to git server
3. run `pod update` in final app to see the result, if anything goes wrong, redo the process?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve mentioned in article you have to:

- Setup private PodSpecs repository (follow guide on CocoaPods site)
- Once you have that you can use `pod '<pod name>', :head`
- Obviously you
  don't want to push code before making sure that it works, for that
  purpose

you should have two lines in podfile for each pod for example:

```
#uncomment this line before pushing
#pod 'HBToolkit'
#use this line for local development(path to podspecs from your working copy of pod project)
pod 'HBToolkit', :path => '../HBToolkit.podspec'
```

Every time you want to make local development of HBToolkit while you    are in project that uses it you have to uncomment second line andu    run `pod install`. Once you've finished. Push HBToolkit changes.     Comment second line, uncomment first one and run `pod install`.  Now    you have same changes but now pulled from repo.